# Changing \renewcommand{\familydefault}{...} back to default

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I just have a quick question: how can I change this command back to the default?

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}
```

**Addendum** - Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet} 
\renewcommand\familydefault{phv} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Test} 
\section{Test2} 
This is normal Text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Would you please expand your question stating more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I wanted to change the text-style to helvet for testing and found this command on the web so i typed it in to see the effect. But i didnt like the font, so i tried to out-comment the command for changing it back, but it didnt help. The normal text changed back to the default font, but the title didnt. Thats what i was trying to do.

Comment: Comment out the two lines: `\usepackage{helvet}` issues the `\renewcommand` anyway.

Comment: i did outcomment it, bothlines, but it didnt help

Comment: Please, try producing a minimal example. Are you sure you refreshed the PDF viewer to show the new version?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}

%\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test2}
This is normal Text
\end{document}

Comment: Sorry for the mess with the code...

Comment: Try `\renewcommand\familydefault{cmr}` or just `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont` for plain text. But I think the `helvet` package changes a lot of things, so you should use it only if you really want to typeset your whole document in Helvetica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `scrbook` class uses a sans serif font for the section titles (which is Computer Modern Sans Serif and not Helvetica); to get roman section titles use

```
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
```

The string `sectioning` can also be `disposition` (with the same effect).

Comment: You can also use `sectioning` which is an alternative name.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel And is also better; I'd wish that the documentation had this one as the main one and `disposition` (which means nothing, IMO) as a possible alias.

Comment: Indeed! It's more clear.